# readline on a gzip file results in an infinite loop [python]

Tags: python, unicode, gzip

I have a gzip file and I'm trying to read the lines of the file:

```
g = gzip.open(filename)

while True:
    dline = g.readline()

    if not dline:
        print "<<" + dline + ">>"

g.close()
```

The output of the above is:

```
<<>>
<<>>
<<>>
<<>>
... infinitely
```

What is wrong here? P.S. The gzip is of a utf-8 text file.

Comment: You can iterate over the lines with `for dline in g:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no condition that can possibly exit your loop. Try:

```
while True:
    dline = g.readline()
    if not dline:
        break
    print "<<" + dline + ">>"
```

The `readline()` family of functions returns an empty string when there are no more lines to read.

Comment: I really cannot believe this... PS: I will mark yours as the right answer.

Comment: Not to worry, it happens to all of us. :)